# Membership renewal not updating contributions correctly

Tags: civimember, contributions

When doing back office "offline" membership renewals (cash, cheque, phone) we have recently noticed that when we select "Renew" from the "Active Membership" window the membership dates are updated correctly but the contribution is recorded as 0.00. I just ran a test and created a new member with a cash payment of membership fee and the amount was correctly recorded in contributions at that stage. When I then used "Renew" to renew the membership the corresponding contribution is listed as 0.00. (The amounts in the forms for processing the renewal are correct.)

Rather new to CiviCRM and I apologise if I am missing something obvious, but this has me baffled. Fortunately we are not using CiviCRM for our accounting.

Re:CiviCRM 4.6.15, on Drupal 7

Comment: Does this also happen on the drupal 4.6 demo site? http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/

Comment: Good question.  Thanks for the tip. No it does not happen on the demo site. I just tested the same process I described above and the Contribution amount is correctly registered for the renewal.  That points to a local implementation problem but I am not sure where to look (or rather tell the support people where to look).  We discovered this problem on our existing site (4.3 on Drupal 6) and hoped that a new installation of CiviCRM on Drupal 7 (currently our test site) would fix it.  Not so, apparently.

Answer (score 2):

We have resolved this issue and it was related to a deleted Organisation contact still being associated with a membership type.

You might be able to resolve it in the interface by re-saving each membership type, especially where an associated Organisation has been deleted / changed to the same name but a new ID.

I actually made the change in the database so this could be your second option. The 'civicrm_price_field' table stores the Organisation ID in the 'name' column, for some reason this hadn't got updated to the new Organisation ID.